# SQL JSON - Concatenate multiple rows into a single JSON string

Tags: sql, json, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create the below JSON from a SQL query using FOR JSON feature.

```
"lineStrings": [
"[[[-0.340254,51.605946],[-0.340278,51.605685],[-0.339718,51.604400], 
[-0.339280,51.603746],[-0.338915,51.603454],[-0.338657,51.603018]]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And your data currently looks like...

Comment: From what query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Please try this / let me know if it's what you're after.  [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b0fa73da3fa203d0b95bf8f8806772a7)

```
declare @myTable table (a decimal(12,8), b decimal(12,8))
insert @myTable (a, b)
values (-0.340254,51.605946),(-0.340278,51.605685),(-0.339718,51.604400),(-0.339280,51.603746),(-0.338915,51.603454),(-0.338657,51.603018)

select string_agg(c,',') as lineStrings
from
(
    select 1 ignore, JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY('[]', 'append $', a), 'append $', b) 
    from @myTable
) x(ignore, c)
group by ignore
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

ps. There's some useful examples in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for some common issues.

---

#### Original Attempt

Here's a hacky solution which uses the standard `for json auto` output, then manipulates the resulting string using the `replace` function.  Since you're working only with numbers it's safe, but I wouldn't risk it if you had any text fields.

There's likely a better way, but I'm not sure what that is...

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(jsonString,'"a":',''),'"b":',''),'{','['),'}',']') hackedJson
, jsonString returnedJson
from
(
    select *
    from 
    (
        values (-0.340254,51.605946),(-0.340278,51.605685),(-0.339718,51.604400),(-0.339280,51.603746),(-0.338915,51.603454),(-0.338657,51.603018)
    ) myTable (a, b)
    FOR JSON AUTO
) j( jsonString)
```

Comment: Thank you John, perfect!